# Manipulating these trigonometric equations with powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, exponentiation

If $5^x = \cos y$ and $a^x = \sin y$, then what is $\cos(2y)$ equal to?

I have tried squaring the first equation and then replacing the $\cos^2(x)$ with $1 - \sin^2 x$, and substituting into the second equation, but that has led me nowhere. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Once you square $\cos y$ and $\sin y$ use the identity

$$\cos 2y = \cos^2 y - \sin^2 y$$